# How to get data from two different table to edit form in admin ui grid

Tags: magento2

Below is code For DataProvider in Edit form.
 Here it displays main tables data while i choose edit them.
 Can any one tell how to display data of another table

```
 <?php
 namespace My\Module\Model\Save;
 use My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save\CollectionFactory;
 class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $contactCollectionFactory
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */

public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $contactCollectionFactory,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->collection = $contactCollectionFactory->create();

    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
}

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    $this->loadedData = array();

    /** @var Customer $customer */
    foreach ($items as $contact) {
        // notre fieldset s'apelle "contact" d'ou ce tableau pour que magento puisse retrouver ses datas :
        $this->loadedData[$contact->getId()]['contact'] = $contact->getData();
    }


    return $this->loadedData;

}
}
```

this is my collection

```
 <?php

 namespace My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save;

 use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

 class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('My\Module\Model\Save', 'My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save');

}
}
```

where my second table name is my_module_contact_add
and fields i want to join is address, zipcode and country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php
 namespace My\Module\Model\Save;
 use My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save\CollectionFactory;
 class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
 {
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $contactCollectionFactory
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */

public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $contactCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $collection = $contactCollectionFactory->create();

     $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['ca'=>'my_module_contact_add'],
                "ca.con_id = main_table.id",
                [
                'con_id' => 'ca.con_id',
                'address' => 'ca.address',
                'zipcode' => 'ca.zipcode',
                'country' => 'ca.country',
                ]
            );

    $this->collection = $collection;   


}

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    $this->loadedData = array();

    /** @var Customer $customer */
    foreach ($items as $contact) {
        // notre fieldset s'apelle "contact" d'ou ce tableau pour que magento puisse retrouver ses datas :
        $this->loadedData[$contact->getId()]['contact'] = $contact->getData();

    }

    return $this->loadedData;

}
}
```

this way i join my table to get data

Comment: thank you, this answer give me clue to load other table data for dynamic form in the ui component form

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'ticket_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was

Answer (score 0):

The "ugly" method. You can try to just load collection of second table and assign columns you want.

Better way is to use for example leftJoin on collection init

```
     public function _initSelect()
     {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('SECOND_TABLE_NAME')],
        'main_table.COULMN_NAME_TO_JOIN_TABLE1 = secondTable.COULMN_NAME_TO_JOIN_TABLE2',
        ['COLUMN_U_WANT_TO_ADD'=>'COLUMN_NAME_OF_NEW_COLUMN']
        );
        $this->addFilterToMap('COLUMN_U_WANT_TO_ADD', 'secondTable.COLUMN_NAME_OF_NEW_COLUMN');
     }
```

Comment: Where to Use this code?

Comment: On collection init.
I created my own collection, (CRUD), and in Collection.php there is function _initSelect() which loads collection from db. There after collection loads i added this code to join column from other table
I'm not sure this is the proper way, but works for me

Comment: i have edited my question ,please you can show me the code since i am new to Magento, Thank you for your help

Comment: Yea, and in "Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection" file that you extends there is a _initSelect() function, so you can try to extends this function by creating in your Collection.php file upper function

Comment: i have done as you said i got this error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `st`.`con_id`, `st`.`address`, `st`.`zipcode`, `st`.`country` FROM `my_module_contact` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `my_module_contact_add` AS `st` ON main_table.id = st.con_id WHERE (`id` = '56')"

Answer (score 0):

In Your

> Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName\Collection.php

Do Something Like That

```
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
    /**
     * Collection constructor
     *
     *
     * @param  EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param  LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param  FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param  ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param  StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param  AdapterInterface $connection
     * @param  AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init('My\Module\Model\Save', 'My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save');
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
    /**
     *
     *  Filtering Data By Query on the Basis of Filtering Criteria
     *
     *
     */

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.reserved_order_id NOT IN (SELECT sales_order.increment_id  FROM sales_order) ');
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error "Type Error occurred when creating object: My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save\Collection"

Comment: run `php bin\magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: yes its working now but its not showing data from the different table

Comment: is there any relation between both of your table??

Comment: yes i have assigned foreign key in second table

Comment: please comment your SQL query which you want to excute? i will add Magento Code for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97581/discussion-between-waqar-ali-and-hardik-radadiya).

Comment: i got solution Thank you for support